# Python SMTPLIB does not connect

Tags: python, smtplib

Hi I am trying to connect to the outlook server to sending the email with `smtplib` in python.

Trying this code `smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com')` does not print out anything and also does not return an error.

Can somebody tell me what might be the problem and how to fix it.

Thank you a lots.

Comment: to be clear, the command to the outlook server did not suceeded. The python command prompt just stuck. I cannot type the next command or do anything except for closing the command prompt and open it again

Comment: Since this question pops up at the top of Google when you search for smtplib connecting issues I wanted to share my solution. I had the same issue, however if I set the connection timeout to e.g. 2 seconds it would "time out" but it actually didn't fail and the email was sent successfully. Turns out the VPN I was using was causing the issue and after disconnecting from the VPN it worked without setting a low timeout.

Comment: Please, select the correct answer or explain the solution if you found it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (make sure your outlook host_name is correct)

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP(host_name, port_number)

server.login(username, password)

#Send the mail
email_content = 'Helloooooooooooooo!' 
server.sendmail(sender_address, target_address, email_content)
```

Where *host_name*, *port_number*, *username*, *password*, *sender_address* and *target_address* are variables you have to fill

See the docs for [SMTP](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

Comment: Well the program just stop. it does not prompt me to type the next command. So i cannot do anything with it.

Comment: Can you show us the code before and after that line?

Comment: >>> import smtplib  >>> smtpObj=smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com')  - ( so you can see instead of showing the new >>> for typing the next command, it just so this sign '-' and I cannot type or do anything with the command prompt, it just stuck there as long as you keep the command prompt open

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mail server required authentification (username, password).

See login-function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.login

Comment: I cannot come to the authentication step because after I enter the command to connect to the smtp, the program just running forever. It does not allow me to write the next command also.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all your answer, the problem is actually caused  because of some restriction in my work network. I have talked with them and the problem is solved.

Comment: Little bit late for a question about this but do you know what the network restriction was? I am in the same situation where when I'm using my work WI-FI I can't connect. But with my own mobile data it works perfectly.